# Matrices homework problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Any help with this question would be greatly appreciated!

I understand I should be using invertibility and skew-symmetric so ,

Inverse: $M.M = I$ and,

Skew-symmetric: $m_{ij}$ = Transpose of $m_{ji}$ and,

Transpose of $M = -M$

but I have played around with this and can't quite figure out how I can prove that $n$ is even.

> Let $M$ be an $n × n$ matrix.
>   $M$ is called skew-symmetric if its transpose is equal
>   to $−M$. Assume that $M$ is skew-symmetric and invertible. Prove
>   that $n$ is even.

Comment: $\det(A)=\det(A^T)=\det(-A)=(-1)^n\det(A)$ and $\det A\ne0$.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

> $A=(a_{ij})_{n\times n}$ is invertable, if $\det A \neq 0$
>
> $A=(a_{ij})_{n\times n}$ is a skew-symmetric matrix, so $A^T=-A$ i.e., if $a_{ij}=-a_{ji}$

${}$

> For a $n \times n$ matrix $A$,
>
> $1.$ $\det (A) = \det (A^T)$ and
>
> $2.$ $\det (cA)=c^n \det A$

${}$

So here $\det (M)=\det (M^T)=\det (-M)=(-1)^n \det (M)$, as $M=(m_{ij})_{n\times n}$ is a Skew-symmetric matrix.

Now **if $n$ is odd**, then $\det (M) =-\det (M)\implies 2\det (M)=0\implies \det (M)=0$, i.e., $M$ is not invertible.

> The determinant of an $n×n$ skew-symmetric matrix $A$ is zero if $n$ is odd.
> ${}$

---

---

If the dimension of a skew-symmetric matrix is **even** i.e., if **$n$ is even**, then $$\det (M)=\det (M^T)=\det (-M)=(-1)^n \det (M)=\det (M)$$ so **we do not have any conclusion about $\det(M)$**.

The determinant of a skew-symmetric matrix $M$ of even dimension is the square of a polynomial, called the **Pfaffian**, in the entries of $M$.

As a corollary, this determinant is thus non-negative.

For example: $M=\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & k \\
-k & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$ be a skew-symmetric matrix.

Now $\det(M)=\begin{vmatrix} 
0 & k \\
-k & 0 
\end{vmatrix}=0-k(-k)=k^2$

so the Pfaffian is $k$.

In the $2×2$ case, then, any skew-symmetric matrix is nonsingular with a positive determinant, except the zero matrix.

Ref:

$1.$ https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-determinant-of-every-skew-symmetric-matrix

$2.$ http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Pfaffian.html